# How to write ETW event logs in python?

Tags: python, etw

In c#, we can see ETW event logs in 'Diagnostic Events viewer' by configing some Eventsources. Now I want to implement the same function(write ETW event logs) in python, can anyone give me some suggestions?

I have use win32evtlogutil.ReportEvent() to write some Windows Event Logs, and can see these logs in 'Event Viewer'-'Windows Logs'-'Application and Services Logs', but the ETW events are different from the Windows Event Logs, the ETW events cannot be seen in 'Event Viewer'. I also have used the pywintrace, but it can not write event logs, it only captures events, so it does not meet my requirements.

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2017/09/pywintrace-python-wrapper-for-etw.html)?

Comment: But it cannot provide events, just analyse events? I need to write events to ETW.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check-out [PyEtw](https://pypi.org/project/pyetw/). PyEtw uses Pythons standard logging facility, and implements a handler that writes the records as ETW events via Microsoft TraceLogging.

Note that the provider GUID is automatically derived from the logger name, so you need to prefix the tracelog `-guid` option argument with a star, for instance `-guid *root` for the `root` logger.

GitHub repo and examples can be found here: https://github.com/mgtek/pyetw